# Sum of two rank deficient matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Suppose I have two $m\times n$, where $m>n$, matrices $A$ and $B$. The rank of $A$ and the rank of $B$ are strictly less than $n$.

Are there any (general) sufficient conditions under which one can guarantee that the rank of sum $A+B$  is strictly less than $n$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $\ker(A)\cap \ker(B)\neq \{0\}$, then you know that $\ker(A+B)$ will not be empty. This is because $(A+B)x=Ax+Bx=0$ if $Ax=Bx=0$.

Of course this is not a neccesary condition, but it is sufficient.

Answer (score 6):

Noting that

$\qquad\text{im}(A+B)\;\text{is a subspace of im}(A) + \text{im}(B)$,

an easy sufficient condition is

$\qquad\text{rank}(A)+\text{rank}(B) < n$,

since then
\begin{align*}
\text{rank}(A+B) 
&=\dim(\text{im}(A+B))\\[4pt]
&\le\dim(\text{im}(A) + \text{im}(B))\\[4pt]
&\le\dim(\text{im}(A)) + \dim(\text{im}(B))\\[4pt]
&=\text{rank}(A) + \text{rank}(B)\\[4pt]
&<n
\end{align*}

Comment: It should be noted that if the ranks sum to less to $n$, then the intersection of the kernels will be nontrivial, so this is a weaker condition than the other answer.

Comment: @Paul: Agreed, but there's no other condition that works based only on the knowledge of the ranks of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: that's true, which is why I upvoted.

Comment: I find the notation $\operatorname{im} A + \operatorname{im} B$ confusing: one might wonder if you mean the direct sum $\operatorname{im} A \oplus \operatorname{im} B$ instead of the union $\operatorname{im} A \cup \operatorname{im} B$.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: im$(A)$ is a subspace, as is im$(B)$, and the sum of two subspaces is a subspace..It's an ordinary sum of subspaces, not a union, and not a direct sum.

Comment: Alright, so it's the _span_ / convex hull of the union.

Comment: leftaroundabout: It's the span, not the convex hull, but ordinary sum of subspaces is standard terminology and notation. If $W$ is a vector space, and $U,V$ are subspaces of $W$, then by definition, $U+V=\{u+v\mid u \in U, v \in V\}$.